What's this plant with saw-toothed leaves, scaly stems and white pom-pom flowers?

Saw this when visiting the gardens at Castle of Mey on 23rd May on the north coast of Scotland. Can anyone identify this? (The one with saw-toothed leaves, scaly stems and white pom-pom flowers.)

It's Ranunculus aconitifolias flore pleno - common name aconite-leaf buttercup, though that name largely refers to the single flowered version. It's a hardy herbaceous perennial which prefers moisture retentive soil.
